# Open Source SOA Stack

Tags: open-source, soa, esb, eai

I'd be evaluating Open Source SOA solutions. What are the options? 
I'm looking for something that provides (possibly) complete SOA stack.

I'd like below features -

1. BPEL
2. BPM
3. ESB
4. SOA Governance
5. Good tooling

Right now Glassfish ESB looks like a good option. Are there other good Stacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got done reading "Open Source SOA" a few months back.  It goes over alot of the open source stuff related to SOA and does a good compare/contrast between the various options.  I'd highly recommend looking at this.

[http://www.amazon.com/Open-Source-Soa-Jeff-Davis/dp/1933988541/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1267534865&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988541)

Comment: I am going through the book and it provides good coverage of above topics in addition to some extra knowledge.
Marking this is accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

WSO2 provides a complete open source SOA stack. And it's the only vendor who provides a complete SOA stack from data to screen, running both on-premise and in the cloud.

WSO2 SOA stack includes...

- WSO2 ESB
- WSO2 Business Process Server [BPEL]
- WSO2 Application Server[Service and Web Ap hosting]
- WSO2 Identity Server [OpenID,WS-Trust,XACML, OAuth, SAML2]
- WSO2 Business Activity Monitor
- WSO2 Business Rules Engine
- WSO2 Data Service Server [Expose you data as a service]
- WSO2 Mashup Server
- WSO2 Gadget Server
- WSO2 Message Broker
- WSO2 Complex Event Processing Server
- WSO2 Governance Registry

You can get more details about WSO2 SOA stack visiting http://wso2.org

Disclaimer : I am an architect working @ WSO2.

Answer (score 4):

[Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/display/MULE2INTRO/Home) is a very popular open source ESB tool.
If Mule/Glassfish provide a lot of functionality you don't really need, maybe a combination of [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) and [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) is the sweet spot for you.

Comment: I don't think that Mule Community Edition covers the requirement of the OP, nor does Sping Integration and ActiveMQ is more a message broker.

Answer (score 4):

I've mentioned several open source ESB in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254043/what-is-the-best-java-based-esb-solution-available/2254258#2254258) but, given your requirements, I'd short list [ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/), [JBossESB](http://www.jboss.org/jbossesb) and [OpenESB](https://open-esb.dev.java.net/).

I don't have much experience with JBossESB but I received good feedback from trustable sources and I know it has good tooling. OpenESB is definitely a serious candidate (although there is a little incertitude about its future). I don't find the documentation of Service Mix perfect (hard to find things).

So my choice would be between OpenESB and JBossESB (note that they don't cover governance which is actually more a human than a technical issue in my opinion).

Answer (score 3):

[Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org) provides an ESB infrastructure that will do SOA in an extremely full featured way.  [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) can also be plugged into ServiceMix for enhanced routing and messaging rules.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seriously looking at Sun GlassFish ESB.  Although I'm a .net developer the tooling and examples (and book on amazon) are very good and easy to use.  It does not cover the governance but very strong BPEL - For what I want I do not even have to know Java - bonus.

Comment: also installs and run in windows without knowing an Linux voodoo

Answer (score 2):

Something I have been working for scientific workflows using service-oriented technologies might be useful to you. It's called [OMII-UK](http://www.omii.ac.uk/) and the distribution by now contains quite a stack of features. All based on opensource techs (e.g., Tomat, Axis, ActiveBPEL, Eclipse BPEL...). Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

Progress FUSE (Apache ServiceMix) is an answer to the lack of documentation with pure ServiceMix.

You can use Apache ODE to integrate BPEL.

Good set of tutorials found here:

http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.com/